# How to set all options to selected from multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery

I have a jsp form in which the user is presented with multiple select boxes from which they can choose multiple options:

```
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">Team Leaders<br />
    <form:select id="teamLeader" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamLeader"/>
</td>
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">HODs<br />
    <form:select id="teamHod" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamHod"/>
</td>
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">Directors<br />
    <form:select id="teamDir" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamDir"/>
</td>
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">Members<br />
    <form:select id="teamPersons" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamPersons"/>
</td>
```

When the user clicks save, I want all options from all select boxes to be set to selected. I can achieve this by using a little jQuery method for each select box as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#saveButton').click(function () {
        jQuery('#teamPersons').each(function () {
            jQuery('#teamPersons option').attr("selected", "selected");
        });
    });
});
```

However the problem is that I have to write a method for each of the 4 select boxes. Is there an easier way to do this i.e. write a single jQuery method to set all options to selected?

Comment: ALL the options are selected? Isn't that counter to what the select list is for? Anyway - if you add a `class` to each `select`, you can just do `$(".myList").each(function(){ //etc });`

Comment: you have already done it.

Comment: @SpaceBison The user is presented with a list of Person objects, from which they choose who are team leaders, HODs, etc. Each Person object chosen goes into the relevant select box. So when Save is clicked , I need to retrieve the person objects from each select box.

Comment: @Neriyan Ok - I see. Added an answer which I think suits your requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to select every single item on click, would be as follows:

`$("select[multiple] option").prop("selected", "selected");`

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vYzUS/

In the fiddle, I've omitted the button click and turned the HTML into dummy HTML. I've also (arbitrarily) added the multiple attribute, incase you have any other `select` lists that you do *not* want to be selected. It *might* be more advisable to wrap the ones you do want to select in a `div` with an `id`, as it will give the selector a better focus.

I've also used `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` - `.prop()` was introduced in jQuery **1.7** and  is specifically for retrieval/setting of property values.

Comment: Thank you! This solution works perfectly for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a function for each select box, just this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#saveButton').click(function() {
        jQuery('select.myClass option').attr("selected","selected");
    });
});
```

HTML with classes

```
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">Team Leaders<br />
    <form:select id="teamLeader" class="myClass" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamLeader"/>
</td>
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">HODs<br />
    <form:select id="teamHod" class="myClass" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamHod"/>
</td>
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">Directors<br />
    <form:select id="teamDir" class="myClass" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamDir"/>
</td>
<td rowspan="4" colspan="1">Members<br />
    <form:select id="teamPersons" class="myClass" multiple="multiple" size="10" path="teamPersons"/>
</td>
```

so only select boxes with class myClass will be switched on click.

Comment: This will only select all the options in the last list.

Comment: oops, I've missed that, thank you for pointing out, I'll update the answer

Comment: @AlecTMH This works however I have other select boxes on my form and these also get all their options selected, which is undesirable. Thank you for taking the time to assist.

Comment: In this case you can set the same class for all selects which need to be applied. I'll update the answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. As jQuery will implicitly use loops via the selectors. If you want to make it explicit as loop, then use your method (IMO that is not necessary).

You can do like this.

```
$("#teamPersons option").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: This will only select the options in the last list, not all the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can select them all in this way:

```
$("select option").prop("selected", "selected");
```

or

```
$("select option").attr("selected", "selected");
```

And you can remove all selected options by:

```
 $("select option").prop("selected", false);
```

or

```
$("select option").attr("selected", false);
```

or

```
$("select option").attr("selected", "");
```